# How to change state of phone to silent mode on some particular incoming number?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-studio

Only for incoming numbers whose first 7 digits are "+91 140".

Comment: what is he crash log ?

Answer (score 0):

**You might be missing this Permissions in android manifest**

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```